# Trying to remove version number from a string using sed in OSX

Tags: regex, macos, bash, sed

I have what I hope is a simple issue which is stumping me. I need to take an installer file with a name like:

```
installer_v0.29_linux.run
installer_v10.22_linux_x64.run
installer_v1.1_osx.app
installer_v5.6_windows.exe
```

and zip it up into a file with the format

```
installer_linux.zip
installer_linux_x64.zip
installer_osx.zip
installer_windows.zip
```

I already have a bash script running on OSX which does almost everything else I need in the build chain, and was certain I could achieve this with sed using something like:

```
ZIP_NAME=`echo "$OUTPUT_NAME" | sed -E 's/_(?:\d*\.)?\d+//g'`
```

That is, replacing the regex `_(?:\d*\.)?\d+` with a blank - the regex **should** match any decimal number preceded by an underscore.

However, I get the error `RE error: repetition-operator operand invalid` when I try to run this. At this stage I am stumped - I have Googled around this and can't see what I am doing wrong. The regex I wrote works correctly at [Regexr](http://www.regexr.com/), but clearly some element of it is not supported by the sed implementation in OSX. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this `sed`:

```
sed 's/_v[^_]*//; s/\.[[:alnum:]]\+$/.zip/' file
installer_linux.zip
installer_linux_x64.zip
installer_osx.zip
installer_windows.zip
```

Comment: Thanks, this is great! Could you explain what I was doing incorrectly and the logic behind this solution? I haven't seen tokens like [[:alnum:]] used before like that.

Comment: `[[:alnum:]]` is POSIX class to match an alphabet or a digit. Your regex matches a digit right after an underscore whereas there is a letter `v`. Besides `\d` is PCRE class that is not supported by `sed`. In sed you need to use `[0-9]` or `[[:digit:]]` for `\d`

Comment: Perfect, very succinct and clear explanation thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `sed`, just some parameter expansion magic with an extended pattern.

```
shopt -s extglob
zip_name=${OUTPUT_NAME/_v+([^_])/}
```

The pattern `_v+([^_])` matches a string starting with `_v` and all characters up to the next `_`. The `extglob` option enables the use of the `+(...)` pattern to match one or more occurrences of the enclosed pattern (in this case, a non-`_` character). The parameter expansion `${var/pattern/}` removes the first occurrence of the given pattern from the expansion of `$var`.

Comment: This is also a great option - would you consider this "better" by any metric than using `sed`, and if so why?

Comment: It's more efficient, since you don't have to start a new process in which to run sed. It's not portable, though, as neither feature is present in the POSIX specification.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way also

```
sed 's/_[^_]\+//' FileName
```

**OutPut:**

```
installer_linux.run
installer_linux_x64.run
installer_osx.app
installer_windows.exe
```

If you want add replace `zip` instead of `run` use below method

```
sed 's/\([^_]\+\).*\(_.*\).*/\1\2.zip/' Filename
```

**Output  :**

```
installer_linux.run.zip
installer_x64.run.zip
installer_osx.app.zip
installer_windows.exe.zip
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me - I get the same out that I put in. Bear in mind I am doing this on OSX.

Comment: The output is the same as the input for me, with this solution. Are you using OSX?